# Manage Groups not listing groups

Tags: groups

None of my groups are listed on the **Manage Groups** option in the Contacts menu. Its applies to all my sites which vary between CiviCRM 5.2 to 5.11. Some are new sites some upgraded from 4.7.x where it worked fine as far as I can remember. The groups are there (for example in a drop down in Find Contacts). I can add a new group, but that doesn't show in the listing either. Also there is no search button on the Find Groups part of the page (it is there in the documentation).

I tried the WordPress sandpit demo and that is the same (though most of the menus are missing (but fortunately Manage Groups was there) so it looks a bit odd and on the Drupal sandpit I couldn't see any menu, so couldn't try there). Nothing in the CiviCRM log at the time I tried.

I'm using WordPress 5.1 and CiviCRM 5.2 to 5.11 on various sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found out what the problem was (or at least how to cure it) and RayWright's Awnser above pointed me in the right direction. I looked at the console and saw some javascript errors (that meant nothing to me) so I tried a different browser, which all worked, so I tried closing my main browser (Firefox) and restarting and everything worked just fine!

The menus on the sandpit sites are now fine so this may have been the same cause or possibly something may have changed on the sandpit sites.

Finally, the Manage Groups screen has changed and the documentation isn't now current. the layout is changed as well as the search button not being there. Searching does work as RayWright suggests.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in 5.7.5 on Drupal 7.64 with no issues, I can see a list of all my groups on this screen (Contacts Menu > Manage Groups).

There isn't actually a search button on this screen - I believe its ajax/javascript that powers the search. After you type something in a field and press enter or tab it refreshes the group listing.

Are there any javascript warnings/clashes in your console?

[image]

Comment: Thanks - that has led me towards putting this right.